# Ros2 bag record from multiple topics using node

Tags: ros2, rosbag2

I would like to record ros2 bag using node(python) and that should subscribe to several topics of different message types, may i know, how to to do that without using loops.

I would like to record like as below, but from multiple topics. Each subscription of all topics to be at same time stamp.
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Recording-A-Bag-From-Your-Own-Node-Py.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! _"...without using loops"_ what does it mean?

Comment: I was trying like this to accomodate multiple topics.
`
    def setup_subscriptions(self):
        topics_and_types = {
            '/topic1': 'your_message_type1',
            '/topic2': 'your_message_type2',
            '/topic3': 'your_message_type3',
        }

        for topic, msg_type in topics_and_types.items():
            self.create_subscription(
                msg_type=msg_type,
                topic=topic,
                callback=self.message_callback,
            )
`

Answer (score 1):

After trying to do it myself, and inspecting the source code for the Writer classes in ros2bag_py library, it looks like it's just not possible. Did you manage to do it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/21672)